# JavaScript object not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am getting localstorage items and then add them into an object. The problem is when I try to get It gives me just one result but It should be six.

```js
(
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fav"))
).forEach(function (e) {
  adUrl = {
    "name": e.name,
    "img": e.img,
  }
});

Object.keys(adUrl).forEach(function (key){
  console.log(adUrl[key]);
});
```

Comment: IMHO, `Array.map` is a better way to map the new objects instead of `forEach`. You are discarding all of the new objects you are creating except for the last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It iterates through all the contents of `fav`, and overwrites `adUrl` each time. *After* it's done with that, this part

```
            Object.keys(adUrl).forEach(function (key) {
                console.log(adUrl[key]);
            });
```

gets executed *once*.

Put it inside the larger `forEach` loop.

Comment: Thank you for replying ...can you show me an example

Comment: Just move the `            })` from just before `Object.keys(//..etc.` to the end of the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you add the object in each iteration to a new array, like this:

```
let myArr = [];
(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fav"))).forEach(function (e) {
  adUrl= {
    "name":e.name,
    "img":e.img,
  }
  myArr.push(adUrl);
});

myArr.forEach(function (adUrl){
  console.log(adUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.map` to map the items from the `localStorage` to the new objects into an *array*.

In your code it is getting overwritten with every iteration and you would end up with the last object that you created.

```
const addUrl = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fav"))).map(({name, img}) => ({name, img}));
addUrl.forEach(obj => {
       console.log(...Object.values(obj));
});
```